# FLuxMonitor locally: FROM address in transaction is wrong

Tags: ethereum, chainlink

I'm trying to run [decentralized-model](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-decentralized-model/) locally. I've managed to deploy:

- Link contract
- AggregatorProxy
- FluxAggregator
- Consumer contract
- Oracle node (offchain)
- External adapters (coingecko + coinapi)

I'm mainly struggling for the last piece which is creating a Job which uses the FluxMonitor initiator.

I've created the following job where "0x5379A65A620aEb405C5C5338bA1767AcB48d6750" is the address of FluxAggregator contract

```
{
"initiators": [
    {
        "type": "fluxmonitor",
        "params": {
            "address": "0x5379A65A620aEb405C5C5338bA1767AcB48d6750",
            "requestData": {
                "data": {
                    "from": "ETH",
                    "to": "USD"
                }
            },
            "feeds": [
                {
                    "bridge": "coinapi_cl_ea"
                },
                {
                    "bridge": "coingecko_cl_ea"
                }
            ],
            "threshold": 1,
            "absoluteThreshold": 1,
            "precision": 8,
            "pollTimer": {
                "period": "15m0s"
            },
            "idleTimer": {
                "duration": "1h0m0s"
            }
        }
    }
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "NoOp"
    }
]
```

}

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it makes my local ganache fail with this error "Error: The nonce generation function failed, or the private key was invalid"

I've put my Ganache in debug mode in order to log requests to the blockchain. Noticed the following call

```
    eth_call
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 28,
  "method": "eth_call",
  "params": [
    {
      "data": "0xfeaf968c",
      "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "to": "0x5379a65a620aeb405c5c5338ba1767acb48d6750"
    },
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

the signature of the function is correct

```
"latestRoundData()": "feaf968c"
```

However , what seems weird is that the from address is "0x0" . Any idea why my Oracle node doesn't use its key to sign the transaction?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Problem from Ganache. In fact , I wrote a truffle script which:

- calls "latestRoundData()" populating the "FROM" with a valid address
- calls "latestRoundData()" populating the "FROM" with a 0x0 address

Then I ran the script 2 times:

1. Connecting to Ganache-cli --> 1st call is successful while the 2nd call fails
2. Connecting to Kovan testnet --> both calls are successful

I've just opened an issue for ganache-cli team: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/840